# Problem with calculating limit $\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,2)}\frac{\sqrt{4-y^2}-2}{x^2}$

Tags: limits

$$\displaystyle\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,2)}\frac{\sqrt{4-y^2}-2}{x^2}$$

which method should be used to calculate or prove non-existence? convert to polar coordinates or look for sequences for which the limits are different so the limit does not exist (if so, which ones)? I've tried both ways and I've been stuck for an hour now. I also tried conjugate multiplication. I'm asking not necessarily for a solution, but at least for a hint.

Comment: $$\lim_{(x,y )\to (0,2)} \frac{\sqrt{4-y2}-2}{x^2}=\frac{-2}{0}$$

do you mean $\lim_{(x,y )\to (0,0)} \frac{\sqrt{4-y2}-2}{x^2}$?

Comment: Oh yes, do you mean $(x,y) \to (0,2)$ or $(x,y) \to (0,0)$?

Comment: @pie the math problem is written correctly. You can't divide by zero, so you have to use a method other than substitution, for example, compare the iterated limits, but in my opinion this method won't work here either.

Comment: @urshuk the limit doesn't exist then it easy to see why let $x \to 0^+$ and $y$ take any path that will converge to to $2$ such that $|y|< 2$ then the limit is $- \infty$ when $x \to 0^-$ the limit will be $+ \infty $ i.e the limit doesn't exist

Comment: The way the problem is written, this limit does not exist. Numerator is not zero, denominator is. End of story

Comment: Since the numerator tends to $-2$ and the denominator to $0^+$, what can we conclude?

Comment: @pie How can it be $+\infty$?

Comment: @user I made a mistake, I forgot that there is a square in the denominator so it is $-\infty $

Comment: Thanks everyone, I got it.

Comment: @pie Don't worry! At first I also was mislead in the evaluation!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly note that $\sqrt{4-y^2}$ requires $4-y^2\ge 0 \iff -2\le y \le 2$ therefore $y$ can approach $2$ only on the left side.

Now, the numerator tends to $-2$ and the denominator to $0^+$, from here we can clearly conclude or we can also use that eventually

$$-\frac{\sqrt{4-y^2}-2}{x^2}\ge \frac{1}{x^2}\to \infty$$

The case

$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{\sqrt{4-y^2}-2}{x^2}$$

which is in the indeterminate form $\frac 0 0$ is much more interesting.

Answer (score 1):

The usual conjugation method works.

As long as $x \ne 0$ and
$|y| \le 2$,

$\begin{array}\\
\dfrac{\sqrt{4-y^2}-2}{x^2}
&=\dfrac{\sqrt{4-y^2}-2}{x^2}\dfrac{\sqrt{4-y^2}+2}{\sqrt{4-y^2}+2}\\
&=\dfrac{(4-y^2)-4}{x^2(\sqrt{4-y^2}+2)}\\
&=-\dfrac{y^2}{x^2(\sqrt{4-y^2}+2)}\\
\end{array}
$

(I corrected mistakes
in the last two lines above.)

so, if
$\dfrac{y^2}{\sqrt{4-y^2}+2}=z$,
for any positive $c$
we can make
$\dfrac{z}{x^2}=c
$
by setting
$x=\sqrt{z/c}$.

Therefore
you can make the quotient
take any negative value
so the limit does not exist.

Comment: Sorry I don't get te point, how can we make the quotient $\frac y x$ take any negative value?

Comment: Moreover, isn't it $\dfrac{(4-y^2)-4}{x^2(\sqrt{4-y^2}+2)}$?

Comment: Both of you are correct. I corrected my error. Fortunately my conclusion is still correct.

Comment: Sorry but still it is not much clear to me since $ \dfrac{y^2}{\sqrt{4-y^2}+2}=z \to 2$ and $x\to 0$. Why do not conlcude from here $$-\dfrac{y^2}{x^2(\sqrt{4-y^2}+2)} \to -\infty \left( -\frac 2{0^+}\right)$$